# How to override LayoutSublayersOfLayer behavior of Xamarin.IOS UIButton?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, uibutton, xamarin.ios

I'm porting to Xamarin.IOS a swift library that makes some material design animation with UIButton.

The swift counterpart is a subclass of UIButton and overrides layoutSublayersOfLayer.

Swift:

```
public override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
    if self.layer == layer {
        layoutShape()
        layoutVisualLayer()
    }
}
```

On Xamarin side I noted that this method is called through CALayerDelegate, which is associated with CALayer through de property Delegate. 
I tried to subclass CALayerDelegate and replace de Delegate property, but when I did that the button didn't rendered correctly and stopped respond to events.

**Is there a way to override layoutSublayersOfLayer on Xamarin.Ios ? Is there another method that I can override to prepare stuff before a particular layer is drawn ?**

```
public class MaterialButtonLayerDelegate : CALayerDelegate
{

    private readonly MaterialButton _button;

    public MaterialButtonLayerDelegate(MaterialButton button):base()
    {
        _button = button;
    }

    public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
    {
        if (_button.Layer == layer)
        {
            _button.LayoutShape();
            _button.LayoutVisualLayer();
        }
    }
}

[Register("MaterialButton")]
public class MaterialButton : UIButton
{
    public CAShapeLayer VisualLayer { get; private set; } = new CAShapeLayer();

    public MaterialButton(CGRect frame):base(frame)  
    {
        PrepareView();
    }

    protected void PrepareView()
    {
        Layer.Delegate = new MaterialButtonLayerDelegate(this);

        ContentScaleFactor = MaterialDevice.Scale();
        PrepareVisualLayer();
    }

    protected virtual void PrepareVisualLayer()
    {
        VisualLayer.ZPosition = 0;
        VisualLayer.MasksToBounds = true;
        Layer.AddSublayer(VisualLayer);
    }

    protected virtual void LayoutShape()
    {
        //...
    }

    protected virtual void LayoutVisualLayer()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to do it is extending CALayerDelegate class and setting it as your CAShapeLayer delegate. Be sure to call delegate's base members wherever possible as it performs required bindings behind the scenes.

```
public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
{
    base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);

    if (_button.Layer == layer)
    {
        _button.LayoutShape();
        _button.LayoutVisualLayer();
    }
}
```